# Subscriber metadata information to publisher in ZMQ

Tags: c, zeromq

I am using zmq_socket_monitor service to monitor a ZMQ_REP socket using a thread spawning method. But as far as I know, this service only works on INPROC and not within remote machines.

```
 My Main code:
    void *ctx = zmq_init (1);
    void *rep = zmq_socket (ctx, ZMQ_REP);
    int rc = zmq_socket_monitor (rep, "inproc://monitor.req", ZMQ_EVENT_ALL);

My Thread Code:
    void rep_socket_monitor (void *ctx)
    {
    zmq_event_t event;
    void *s = zmq_socket (ctx, ZMQ_PAIR);
    rc = zmq_connect (s, "inproc://monitor.req");
    while (true) 
    {
        zmq_msg_t msg;
        rc = zmq_recvmsg (s, &msg, 0);
        memcpy (&event, zmq_msg_data (&msg), sizeof (event));
        switch (event.event)
        {
          //Check for events
        }
    }
    }
```

Here if I check for any event, I get the montitored address of my own machine. 
What if some remote machine client tries to connect to me.
How can I obtain its IP address when it gets connected to the port that I am monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

You are hooking up a monitoring socket to a REP socket that is itself *not* bound to any endpoints, thus there is no endpoint available for external parties to connect to.

In your case, for example:

```
void *ctx = zmq_init (1);
void *rep = zmq_socket (ctx, ZMQ_REP);
int rc = zmq_socket_monitor (rep, "inproc://monitor.req", ZMQ_EVENT_ALL);
// Create thread, check error messages...
...
// Bind the REP socket to your external endpoint
rc = zmq_bind (rep, myExternalEndPoint);
```

Have a look at the [zmq_socket_monitor API documentation](http://api.zeromq.org/3-2:zmq-socket-monitor) (for version 3.2.2) for examples of how to set it up.

Things to note:

> Only connection oriented (tcp and ipc) transports are supported in this initial implementation.
>
> **ZMQ_EVENT_CONNECTED: connection established**
> The ZMQ_EVENT_CONNECTED event triggers when a connection has been established to a remote peer. This can happen either synchronous or asynchronous.

Comment: Sorry Jacob, I did not mention my entire code:
After creating the thread, I had a bind in place:
    rc = zmq_bind (rep, "tcp://*:5562");

I am able to send and receive data from a remote client. Hence the binding at REP and connecting at REQ must be 

successful.

My issue is that out of all the events, I can see only listening, accepting and disconnecting events being shown on the 

monitored socket.

For Example:
accepted socket descriptor 212
accepted socket address tcp://0.0.0.0:5562

I tried the client exe on a different machine and yet I was unsuccessful to achieve its IP address.

Answer (score 0):

The messages read from the monitor socket have 2 frames:

- event number (16bit) + event value (32bit)
- name of the affected endpoint for TCP and IPC

The documentation is doesn't state it explicitly, but the endpoint refers to the *local* endpoint of the socket: the ip/port you're bound to. To get the *remote* endpoint (ip/port of the connecting peer), first you need the connection file descriptior: the event value for the ZMQ_EVENT_CONNECTED event. Then call getpeername on the obtained fd with something like this:

```cpp
std::string getPeerName(int socketFd) {
    sockaddr_storage sockaddrStore;
    socklen_t len = sizeof(sockaddrStore);

    sockaddrStore.ss_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    getpeername(socketFd, (sockaddr*)&sockaddrStore, &len);

    if (sockaddrStore.ss_family == AF_INET) {
        char addrstr[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
        sockaddr_in* sockaddrin = (sockaddr_in*)&sockaddrStore;

        inet_ntop(AF_INET, &sockaddrin->sin_addr, addrstr, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
        return std::string("tcp://") + addrstr;
    }

    return "<unknown>";
}
```